# Sonata Admin Bundle and roles may explain to me how it works

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

It's the first that i use the Sonata Admin Bundle. It's looks like pretty cool. 
But if somebody can explain to me something particular with the differents roles and the display.

With a role : ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN
It's display only my entities but not the sidebar.

With a role : ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN
It's display in the sidebar but not my entites.

It's could be very great to merge the both. Thank you for your advices and your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should simply assign both roles.

`ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN` is from SF2, `ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN` is from Sonata.

Comment: Thank you. I thought that i need to assign just only one role.